# How can I pan, right to left, in a "wide" video output to 1080p?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a wide video, 6720x1080, that I want to pan across from right to left, and output to a 1920x1080 view over the length of the video. Is it possible to do this with FFMPEG?

Comment: @gyan shouldn't have closed this, as the other question involves an image and I'm trying to "pan" a wide video.

Comment: Makes no difference, Command is the same. See my comment reply there for the change in expression.